# Getting error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C3."

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, transpose

I have a google sheet in which I have two tabs.
I want to add the data of Column 1 from tab 2 transposed to Rows in Tab 1 of the same google Sheet.
Tab 1 name: Student
Tab 2 name: Landlord
Column in Landlord tab: College

I applied the formula `=Transpose(Landlord!B2:B)`. It gave me the error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C3."

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

- It is failing because of the conflict of data in `C3`.

#### Fix:

- What you need to do is either remove/move the data in `C3` currently, or move the transpose formula to a row that doesn't have any data so it won't have any conflict.

#### Your case:

- Transposing `B2:B` is a very long range so it might have been able to occupy the whole row and base on your error, your formula is either located in either `A3` or `B3`. You need the formula to be on a cell where its row is blank. So either move the formula to another row with no data, or delete all data in row `3`.

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

As seen above, `=transpose(A1:A4)` won't expand because of `x` value in `C5`. To proceed, we need to either remove/move `C5` value, or move the formula

#### Output:

1. Move all conflicted cells/data into another row

[image: output1a]

2. Delete row `5` data aside from the formula

[image: output1b]

3. Move the formula to a blank row

[image: output2]